# Dual drawer navigation react native expo

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

I'm trying to implement a left drawer and right drawer for my app. I'm unable to find any usable examples online. I've tried 3-4 examples including the example from react native docs itself and I'm getting `undefined is a not an object (evaluating'Component.router)`. If anyone has a working example of an app with a left and right drawer navigator that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could do something like this, create a new file 'AppNav.js' to handle all your navigation/drawers etc~

**AppNav.js**

```
const LeftDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
    },
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
    },

  }, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.6,
    drawerPosition: 'left',
  })

const RightDrawer = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: {
      screen: Screen1,
    },
    Screen2: {
      screen: Screen2,
    },

  }, {
    headerMode: 'none',
    drawerWidth: SCREEN_WIDTH * 0.6,
    drawerPosition: 'right',
  })

const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  LeftDrawer: { screen: LeftDrawer },
  RightDrawer: { screen: RightDrawer }
})

export default AppNav = props => {
  return <RootNavigator />
}
```

EDIT: Plus, on the **RootNavigator**, before the call of LeftDrawer, you can set the main screen of your app and set it as 'initialRouteName'